# Is there something special about Corona that makes it suitable for adding a slice of lime?

Tags: garnish

Corona, and some other beers, tend to go well with a slice of lemon inside. Is there something particular about the style of beer, or is this a marketing thing?

Comment: Here in New Zealand I've only seen it served with lemon, not that I drink a lot of Corona.

Comment: Or is there something _missing_ from Corona that makes it require the addition of a lime?

Answer (score 6):

I would say it's the light body, low maltiness and low bitterness that make it amenable to citrus additions (and perhaps other additions.)

The low flavor and bitterness means:

- if you choose to add something, you need only a little of it before you can taste/smell the addition
- there's less "interference" from the flavors of the beer so the addition tastes cleaner

Contrast with adding citrus to a Czech Pils for example. You'd have to add much more juice - the bitterness and malt backbone of the beer would compete with the citrus additions.

Comment: I'm okay without a lime in my Corona, but I was very surprised how much better Land Shark is with lime.

Comment: btw, different citrus fruit go well in different beers.  This can be fun to experiment with.  Some richer orange-type fruit go well with Guiness, for example, and I like calamondin in pilsner.

Answer (score 2):

Don't think it's a marketing trick. Imagine all the costs to get the lemon slices out of the bottles.

Lemon in general goes very good with beer. In Germany (not only there) a mixture of beer and lemonade is very common and famous (called Radler or Alsterwasser).